# org.sqlite.JDBC cannot be cast to javax.sql.DataSource

Tags: java, sqlite, netbeans

I am building a **Java Enterprise** Application using Netbeans 8.0.1 on Linux Mint.
I have to use an existing **SQLite** database so I followed the [tutorial here](http://jakoch.de/2013/07/21/marry-netbeans-sqlite/) to connect Netbeans to it.
Then I wrote a trial Entity class and Session Bean but **when I deploy the application I get the following error**:

```
Grave:   Exception while preparing the app : Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: org.sqlite.JDBC cannot be cast to javax.sql.DataSource
Error Code: 0
Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: org.sqlite.JDBC cannot be cast to javax.sql.DataSource
Error Code: 0
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:316)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DatasourceLogin.connectToDatasource(DatasourceLogin.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.setOrDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.loginAndDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:239)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:681)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:204)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getDatabaseSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:182)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.getDatabaseSession(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:527)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:358)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.loadPU(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:199)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.<init>(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:107)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$1.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:223)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:510)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.createEMFs(JPADeployer.java:230)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.prepare(JPADeployer.java:168)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:922)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:431)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:527)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:523)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:522)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:546)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1423)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1500(CommandRunnerImpl.java:108)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1762)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1674)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandler.service(StaticHttpHandler.java:297)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:246)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: org.sqlite.JDBC cannot be cast to javax.sql.DataSource
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.AbstractDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDataSource.java:121)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:123)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: javax.resource.spi.ResourceAllocationException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: org.sqlite.JDBC cannot be cast to javax.sql.DataSource
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.internalGetConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:319)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:196)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:171)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:166)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.AbstractDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDataSource.java:114)
    ... 51 more
Caused by: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException: org.sqlite.JDBC cannot be cast to javax.sql.DataSource
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.datastructure.RWLockDataStructure.addResource(RWLockDataStructure.java:103)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.addResource(ConnectionPool.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createResourceAndAddToPool(ConnectionPool.java:1512)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createResources(ConnectionPool.java:944)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.initPool(ConnectionPool.java:230)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.internalGetResource(ConnectionPool.java:511)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.getResource(ConnectionPool.java:381)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.PoolManagerImpl.getResourceFromPool(PoolManagerImpl.java:245)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.PoolManagerImpl.getResource(PoolManagerImpl.java:170)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.getResource(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.internalGetConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:307)
    ... 55 more
Caused by: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException: org.sqlite.JDBC cannot be cast to javax.sql.DataSource
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createSingleResource(ConnectionPool.java:924)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createResource(ConnectionPool.java:1189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.datastructure.RWLockDataStructure.addResource(RWLockDataStructure.java:98)
    ... 65 more
Caused by: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException: org.sqlite.JDBC cannot be cast to javax.sql.DataSource
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.allocator.LocalTxConnectorAllocator.createResource(LocalTxConnectorAllocator.java:110)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createSingleResource(ConnectionPool.java:907)
    ... 67 more
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: org.sqlite.JDBC cannot be cast to javax.sql.DataSource
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.DSManagedConnectionFactory.getDataSource(DSManagedConnectionFactory.java:166)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.DSManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(DSManagedConnectionFactory.java:102)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.allocator.LocalTxConnectorAllocator.createResource(LocalTxConnectorAllocator.java:87)
    ... 68 more
```

I search on internet for a solution but but I every time obtain the same exception.

Can somebody help me???

Comment: Looking around on Internet I did't find any good solution, I think that java EE have some problem with SQLite so I am solving making the connection by hand with this:

http://www.codejava.net/java-se/jdbc/connect-to-sqlite-via-jdbc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made several research on my problem but I can not find a fine solution to make everything work so I made a little architectural change moving from a (NetBeans) Java EE Enterprise Application to a (NetBeans) Java web application, I hand made the connection at the database following this guide:
http://www.codejava.net/java-se/jdbc/connect-to-sqlite-via-jdbc
and now everything seem to work good.
It was not a fast solution but works.

Answer (score 0):

Before Moving on to pooling the connections using DataSource, please check first whether single JDBC connection for SQLite is working or not. If yes, then you can pool this datasource using JNDI.

First restart the server.

Then add a reference to a new jdbc resource in your web/META-INF/context.xml file. It defines a JNDI name, its class type, the driver class name that relates to the jar we just installed above, and a url to connect to the database. In my case I’m pointing to a directory (which must exist) on the file system.

```
<Context>
    <Resource name="jdbc/sqlite"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    driverClassName="org.sqlite.JDBC"
    url="jdbc:sqlite:/var/lib/tomcat7/dbs/test.db"
    />
</Context>
```

In addition, you have to add the resource in your web.xml file. Note the name is the same the name above.

```
...
<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/sqlite</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
</resource-ref>
...
```

Now you can make reference to the database in your Java code. This is lifted from the sqlite example page:

```
Connection conn = null;
try {
    Context ctx = new InitialContext();
    DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/sqlite");
    conn = ds.getConnection();
    Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
try {
    statement.executeUpdate("create table thing(x integer)");
} catch (Exception e) { 
     // Could well be already there
}
statement.executeUpdate("insert into thing values(42)");
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select * from thing");
while (rs.next()) {
writer.println("id = " + rs.getInt(1));
} catch (Exception e) {
    writer.println(e.getMessage());
} finally {
    try {
        if (conn != null) conn.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        writer.println(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have any web.xml file and context.xml file
Until now I wrote Enterprise application using the Embedded database of Netbeans so I didn't need of them.
Are you sure I need such files in a Java Enterprice application? That files are typical of the Java Web applications

Comment: Well embedded environment won't work for long as eventually you'll run into issues like this. So please have entire configuration in xml files  . Furthermore, it shall help you debug as well, and your code will be more maintainable & plugable.

Comment: Tank you for the reply, you are really helpful but I have some doubt, can you please suggest me how to create the context.xml file? (I just create the web.xml) and where have I to add the java code?

Comment: context.xml depends on what server you're using. It is inside the server configurations folder. Servers usually provide best factory support for JNDI. Moreover, you can use frameworks as well, who have their own context.xml configurations. Examples include spring,ejb etc.